# NCBIblastPcommandline Errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython, blast

I'm trying to automate blast outputs from several files in a directory. Variables here are hardcoded but will be user defined later on. My infiles will be changed via a loop but i'm having issues running NcbiblastpCommandline on the files from within python. Aiming to run blast locally with inputs of several batches of larger fasta files so blast will run sequentially each batch file,output into a tsv where i parse data and pass to clustalw local alignment.

```
Input_file="minifasta.fasta"
data="uniprot_database"
E_Value_Thresh=1e-10
counter=1
Filename2= 'Batch'+str(counter)
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastpCommandline
blast_output_file='blastout.tsv'
NcbiblastpCommandline.outfile=Filename2
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastpCommandline
cline = NcbiblastpCommandline(query=Input_file, db=data,outfmt=6, 
out=blast_output_file, evalue= E_Value_Thresh)
print(cline)
stdt, stdr= cline()
```

I keep receiving an error saying ''NcbiblastpCommandline' object is not iterable.' and i'm being directed to the stdt,stdr line but without stdt,stdr another error saying the command isnt recogised comes up and error messages directing to stdout_str, stderr_str. I cant find up to date examples of NcbiblastpCommandline usage in python 3 to guide me.

Complete error i receive is:

```
ApplicationError: Non-zero return code 127 from 'blastp -out blastout.tsv -outfmt 6 -query minifasta.fasta -db uniprot_database -evalue 1e-10', message '/bin/sh: blastp: command not found'.

  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/Application/__init__.py", line 523, in __call__
    stdout_str, stderr_str)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To make it easier to help you, could you please (now and in future) provide the complete error you are getting. Also please add what your expected input looks like and what output you want to generate and if you want to run blast local or remote.

Comment: No problem, amending my question now.

Comment: `/bin/sh: blastp: command not found'.` might indicate that you either dont have blastp installed, or its not found in your `PATH` variable. Can you run blastp manually and what OS are you on?

Comment: blastp works on commandline and i have it in the same directory as my .py and all the input/output files. Im on OSX so im wondering if there is a way to implement ./ as i can do on commandline to have blastp execute within the same directory

Comment: Just for completeness, can you perform the command `echo $PATH` in terminal and verify that the location of your blastp is listed? If not, try to add it.  (http://osxdaily.com/2014/08/14/add-new-path-to-path-command-line/ for example shows a way to do this)

Answer (score 3):

First run `which blastp` to find the full path to `blastp` and give that as argument to `NcbiblastpCommandline`.

```
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastpCommandline
blastp_path = '/path/to/blastp'
cline = NcbiblastpCommandline(cmd=blastp_path, query=Input_file, db=data,outfmt=6, 
out=blast_output_file, evalue= E_Value_Thresh)
```

If you now do `print(cline)` it should print out the full command that is going to be run. Doublecheck that this works by copy/pasting this output and running it from the commandline.

Comment: This works! Awesome, glad i didn't have to resort back to using OS.command i find this way more flexible.

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help. If you feel that this answer solved your problem, please [mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem too. I fixed it by adding the path to the NCBI blast commands into my path, and re-opening python. To add the path to blast into your $PATH do this: `export PATH=/path/to/blast:$PATH`. Here are some commands which can solve the problem if you don't know how to do all this:

```
# Find where it is installed and put it in a variable:
# 'command -v blastp' and  'which blastp' will give the same results
path_to_blast=$(dirname $(command -v blastp))
export PATH=$path_to_blast:$PATH
```

Else you can add it to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Put path to executables of blast in a variable
path_to_blast=$(dirname $(command -v blastp))
# Append a comment to the ~/.bashrc
echo -e '\n# Add path to blast executable' >> ~/.bashrc
# Add the export command to update the $PATH.
# Double quotes will allow the inerpretation of the $path_to_blast
echo "export PATH=$path_to_blast:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
# Source the ~/.bashrc to update your session
source ~/.bashrc
```

In both cases, re-open python.
This will work without admin privileges.